# For each xml file in a directory, how to add its contents to another file at a certain place?

Tags: xml, regex, perl, scripting

I have a fun and seemingly simple Perl challenge that is stumping my colleagues. Care to take a crack? It will really help my project move forward.

Iterate through each xmlfileXF in directoryD, and for each one:

1. in modifythisfileMTF, copy wordblockWB and paste it after the last wordblockWB.
2. in modifythisfileMTF, replace replacemeRM with the contents of the current xmlfileXF.

directoryD only has xml files by the way, so really, you don't have to discriminate on filetype. Also, it's fine to hardcode the contents of wordblockWB if you prefer.

modifythisfileMTF.txt contents:

```
myfunc
{
  // begin wordblockWB
  prewords
  "msg"=replacemeRM
  postwords
  // end   wordblockWB

  return 0;
}
```

directoryD contents:

```
xmlfileXF1.xml
xmlfileXF2.xml
...6000 more
```

xmlfileXF1.xml contents:

```
<foo/>
```

xmlfileXF2.xml contents:

```
<bar/>
```

desired output modifythisfileMTF.txt contents:

```
myfunc
{
  // begin wordblockWB
  prewords
  "msg"=<foo/>
  postwords
  // end   wordblockWB

  // begin wordblockWB
  prewords
  "msg"=<bar/>
  postwords
  // end   wordblockWB

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all help, and have fun!

Comment: Are all the XML files one-liners, or can they be longer?  If longer, are you sure you want your output file to have multi-line "msg"=... lines?  Also, the output file is maybe a programming language?  Have you given the exact syntax? No line-ending semi-colons, etc?

Comment: The xml files are all one-liners, with no newlines, yes. I haven't given the exact programming language syntax of the output file; It's not so important. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you like one of the answers below, please don't forget to "accept" the answer, so the author gets credit.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in testing solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.  It prints to STDOUT, so just redirect to a file as needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $directoryD = "/xml files";
my $prewords = "Four score and...\n";
my $postwords = "The End\n";

chdir("$directoryD") or die $!;
opendir(D, ".") or die $!;
my @xmlFiles = grep(/\.xml$/i, readdir(D));
closedir(D);
if (scalar(@xmlFiles) == 0) {
  die "Could not detect any XML files in $directoryD\n";
}

print "myfunc\n";
print "{\n";
foreach my $file (@xmlFiles) {
  # Read the FIRST line from each file.  Ignore any other lines.
  open(F, "$file") or die $!;
  my $line = <F>;
  chomp $line;
  close(F);

  print $prewords;
  print "\"msg\"=$line\n";
  print $postwords;
  print "\n";
}
print "return 0;\n";
print "}\n";
```

Comment: I ran this from the command line of my Ubuntu computer with: /usr/bin/perl myscript >> myanswer.txt     where myscript is the full name of the file where I stored the code from above. It worked like a charm and was easy for me, a very novice perl guy, to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution that prints to stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = shift || '.';

doit(sub {
    my $callback = shift;

    opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
    while(my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        next unless $file =~ /\.xml$/i;

        open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
        chomp(my $line = <$fh>);
        close($fh) or die $!;

        $callback->($line);
    }
    closedir($dh) or die $!;
});

sub doit {
    my $process_files = shift;

    print "myfunc\n{\n";
    $process_files->(sub {
        my $msg = shift;
        print join "\n", map { "\t$_" } (
                '// begin wordblockWB',
                'prewords',
                qq{"msg"=$msg},
                'postwords',
                '// end wordblockWB',
                "\n"
            );
    });
    print "\treturn 0;\n}\n";
}
```

It's a bit verbose but the idea was to keep the file processing code and formatting/output code separate. The extra complexity might not be worth it in this situation though.

Comment: This one also worked, but I had to put the xml files at the same directory level as the script itself, and was a bit more complex. I couldn't figure out how it worked, being novice myself, but it did. I used this to run it: /usr/bin/env perl myscript >> myanswer.txt    where myscript is the file I stored this code in. It surprised me that /usr/bin/env perl worked because I looked at /usr/bin/env, which seems to be a list of aliases and environment variables, and I didn't see anything on my particular system with 'perl' or 'PERL': /usr/bin/env|grep perl